# How to get the json response back in the front end that I am sending from my backend?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I am sending this from the backend.

```js
return res.status(403).json({ message: "User does not exist" });
```

and handling the error on the frontend within the catch of my axios, but when I log the 'err' I get a network error rather than the message. How do I get the message?

```js
.catch(err => {

            console.log(err)
}
```

Comment: It should be a property of the error object, no? What does the output of `console.log(err)` look like?

Comment: Error: Request failed with status code 403
    at createError (createError.js:17)
    at settle (settle.js:19)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:60)
    at XMLHttpRequest.sentryWrapped (helpers.js:87)

Comment: Looking at how [this simple gist](https://gist.github.com/fgilio/230ccd514e9381fafa51608fcf137253) handles errors through axios, I would assume it should be on `err.response.data`. It seems that you're logging the axios wrapper object that contains information about the request, response, etc. but you're only interested in the response.

Comment: This has been an ongoing issue. Take a look at some of the solutions offered here: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/960

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to print the error message in console that you sending from the backend.

```
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err.response.data.message)
}
```